# Possible to have Mysql table with 2 unique columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I currently save game scores using this code:

```
function SubmitScore()
{
global $result, $db;

$playername =  $db->real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST["playername"]));
$score      = $db->real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST["score"]));
$fbusername     = $db->real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST["fbusername"]));
$gamelevel      = $db->real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST["gamelevel"]));
$query1     = "SELECT * FROM leaderboard WHERE playername = '$playername'";
$query2     = "INSERT INTO leaderboard (playername, score,fbusername,gamelevel) VALUES ('$playername', $score,'$fbusername','$gamelevel')";
$query3     = "UPDATE leaderboard SET score = $score WHERE playername = '$playername'";

$scores     = $db->query($query1);

if ($scores->num_rows == 0)
{
    $db->query($query2);
    $result = "0:New entry";
}
else
{
    $row = $scores->fetch_object();
    $oldscore = $row->score;
    if ($score > $oldscore)
    {
        $db->query($query3);
        $result = "0:Successful update";
    } else
        $result = "0:Score was lower than before";
}
}
```

The playername column is unique and inserts a new row for a new player but only updates an existing players score if it is higher than the existing one.

This is fine just for high scores and one level but I need to also need to store the users facebook name and the multipule game levels.
Is it possible to have playername and gamelevel columns to be unique, whereby I can obtain  player 1 level 1, player 1 level 2 etc;
bearing  in mind I also have to keep the high score as well.

John

Comment: What you will want to do is have multiple tables, each storing the player ID, so that they will be able to link back to which player they are for.  A high score table could for example have player id, level, and high score columns, perhaps a datetime as well, to tell when they reached that score.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL supports a combination of columns to be defined as a unique key. If you remove the index for playername and add a new one for playername+level you are set as far as MySQL goes.

This is how it's done with SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE `leaderboard` DROP INDEX `unique_index`;
ALTER TABLE `leaderboard` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`playername`, `gamelevel`);
```